# How to save list of objects in browser local storage flutter web application

Tags: flutter, local-storage, flutter-web, flutter-hive, flutter-html

I am creating a flutter web application where I am trying to handle multi account jut like Gmail. I want when user login the user info store some where in browser storage and after closing the browser the data should not clean. How I can achieve this please help me I'm stuck at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin might work for you. Simply it stores key-value pairs. You can save user details using it in the browser. Then later access it.